# Can the inverse to a scalar multiplication be found efficiently in elliptic curves?

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $P$ be a point over an elliptic curve $F_p$, say Curve25519, and let $k$ be a scalar. Assume I want to find an inverse $k^{-1}$ such that:
$$k \cdot k^{-1} \cdot P = P$$
Does such an inverse always exists and can it be calculated efficiently?

Comment: If you know the order $m$ of the point $P$ (presumably this is the case with the curve of your interest), and you also know $k$, then this amounts to finding a modular inverse of $k$ modulo $m$. That can be calculated quickly. It exists if and only if $\gcd(k,m)=1$. More often than not the curves used in cryptosystems have $m$ a prime number. In that case the gcd condition is automatic. On the other hand, if you don't know $k$, then you are out of luck. The safety of EC-based cryptosystems relies on the fact that knowing $k\cdot P$ and $P$ does not allow us to easily calculate $k$.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed know the order of $k$, but not the order of of point $P$ - I just know the order of the subgroup $P$ is in. I assume this does not work then?

Comment: In particular, I am looking at the Ristretto group, which seems to be a prime order elliptic curve groups -- so does every point there have the same order as the Ristretto base point?

Comment: If $P$ comes from a group of order $\ell$, $\ell$ a prime number, then the order of $P$ is automatically $\ell$ (unless $P$ is the point at infinity, which is uninteresting).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it amounts in a way to the discrete logarithm problem for EC.

Given two points $P,Q$ on an EC curve where $Q$ is a multiple of $P$.
Find $k$ such that $Q=kP$.

This problem is intractable and assures the security of EC cryptography.